# How to filter data in AngularJS like this?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

Okay, I really can't find the right term/words to describe this. Basically, I have a select control and a div with `ng-repeat`

```
<select ng-model="selectedCode" >
    <option value="">ALL</option>
    <option value="A">Option A</option>
    <option value="B">Option B</option>
    <option value="C">Option C</option>
</select>
<select ng-model="selectedName" >
    <option value="">ALL</option>
    <option value="John">John</option>
    <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
</select>


<div ng-repeat="item in myList" ng-if="item.code==selectedCode && item.Name==selectedName" >
 <!--show some data-->
</div>
```

That code kinda works but I have no idea how to show all if the selected item is "ALL".

Comment: ng-if='(item.code==selectedCode && item.Name==selectedName) `|| selectedCode ==  ""`'. use OR condion to make ng-if should return true if you select `All`

Comment: It worked!!! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This Expression will Display all items with the selected code or name, if the other select is set to "ALL". It will also display all items, if both select boxes are set to "ALL". And it will show only the matching items with the correspondant name and code, if none of the select boxes has been set to "ALL".

```
ng-if="(selectedCode==item.code || selectedCode=='') &&
       (selectedName==item.name || selectedName=='')">
```

To preselect a value, so the ng-if gets applied directly after page load, you may add an ng-init Expression for setting a default value, like so.

```
ng-init="selectedCode=''"
ng-init="selectedName='John'"
```

To put all this into a context, here is an example, showing a table with ng-repeat and the two select boxes for utilizing the ng-if Expression. The code "" and the name "John" are preselected and I added the JavaScript block.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <div ng-app="ngApp">
      <select ng-model="selectedCode" ng-init="selectedCode=''">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
        <option value="A">Option A</option>
        <option value="B">Option B</option>
        <option value="C">Option C</option>
      </select>

      <select ng-model="selectedName" ng-init="selectedName='John'">
        <option value="">ALL</option>
        <option value="John" selected="selected">John</option>
        <option value="Peter">Peter</option>
      </select>

      <div ng-controller="ngController">
        <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Code</th>
            <th>Name</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="item in myList" ng-if="(selectedCode==item.code || selectedCode=='') && (selectedName==item.name || selectedName=='')">
            <td>{{item.code}}</td>
            <td>{{item.name}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>

    <script>
      angular.module('ngApp', [])
        .controller('ngController', function($scope) {
          $scope.myList = [ {code:'A', name:'John'}, {code:'B', name:'Peter'}, {code:'C', name:'Peter'} ];
        });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```